# bash - how to get return values from functions that are called asynchronously

Tags: bash

I've got a bash script that calls from main module two functions asynchronously like this:

```
(func1 && print_msg f1) &
(func2 && print_msg f2) &

[...]

wait $(jobs -p)
```

How to return a value from func1 and func2 is easy and has often been discussed. My problem is how to access these return values inside the main module to check for specific values.

Answer (score 2):

If you refer to the *exit status* as function's "return value", then it's easy with `wait`. But if your function returns something more complex than 8-bit integer, and a lot happens between putting the task to background, and the return value retrieval, read on.

#### The simple case

The `wait` built-in you already use, returns the exit status of the background process it waited on (but only if PID was explicitly given):

> `wait` [..] waits for each process identified by an ID, which may be a process ID or a  job specification, and **reports its termination status**.  If ID is not  given, waits for all currently active child processes, and the return status is zero.

For example:

```
$ f() { sleep 5; return 13; }
$ f &
$ wait $!
$ echo $?
13
```

#### A little bit more robust synchronization

The previous example is perfectly safe, since `$!` always returns PID of the last background process in the current shell, and nothing happens between `f &` and `wait`.

In the scenario with some work in between:

```
f &
pid=$!
# work
wait "$pid"
ret=$?
```

there exists a slight chance that `f`'s PID (stored in `pid`) will be recycled -- in case more than `pid_max` processes (defaults to `32768` on Linux) are spawned during `work` section **and** some process spawned in `work` section receives the same PID (as `pid`). Until that happens -- and because `bash` **caches exit statuses of all of its children** -- the exit status of `f` will be tracked, stored and available, even if `f` terminates *before* you call `wait "$pid"`.

If you have many (and/or long-lasting) processes (possibly in a loop) inside the `work` section above, you might want to use a more **robust synchronization mechanism**, or some form of IPC, perhaps named pipes/FIFOs (easily set-up with [`coproc`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Coprocesses)).

FIFO can deliver the result, but also signal the background job completion, so you can use it instead of `wait`:

```
# fifo setup/clean-up
tmp=$(mktemp -td)
mkfifo "$tmp/f"
trap 'rm -rf "$tmp"' EXIT

# async f, push result to fifo
f() { sleep 5; echo "result" >"$tmp/f"; }
f &

# work

# block until f finishes, read result from fifo
f_ret=$(<"$tmp/f")
echo "f done, returned: $f_ret"
```

Comment: Interesting.  I just tested it, and apparently this works even if `wait $!` is invoked after `f &` terminates.

Comment: Would there be a race condition if f terminates, and a new process got the same PID?

Comment: It works probably until the PID is recycled. But there shouldn't be any race conditions, `wait` will then wait for the new process that recycled the PID.

Comment: It's safe in the case with no work between `f` and `wait`, and reasonably safe with even significant work in between (the process that overwrites `pid` would have to be child of the same shell, otherwise the result is unaffected, since `bash` caches exit statuses only of its children). But I've added a alternative, FIFO, approach.